# Read webpage into string

Tags: ocaml

This should be really easy to do but my Google skills are failing me. I want to read a webpage into a string or a list of strings, something similar to "In_channel.read_lines file" in Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several libraries in OCaml that can handle http for you, three comes to mind: ocaml curl, ocamlnet and ocaml-http. I've used only the latter, but it seems, that ocamlnet provides a very convenient function: [`http_get : string -> string`](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-3.4.1/doc/html-main/Http_client.Convenience.html), that do exactly what you want. What concerning `ocaml-http` it also provides nice interface, but it uses monads. For example, this [interface](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp/blob/master/lwt/cohttp_lwt.mli) provides IO functions lifted into LWT monad. And [here](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp/blob/master/async/cohttp_async.mli) is the interface lifted to the async monad.